# Looping the program in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, masm, masm32

I have an assembly program that asks for user input and prints its result. Now I need to create a loop so that the program will continue to prompt the user to enter input again and calculate the result. (Example: Enter "YES" to try another or "NO" to exit the program. The loop needs to continue until "NO" is entered. 
I am new to assembly and am trying to learn. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
 INCLUDE io.h
.STACK 4096

.DATA
n1 DWORD ?
n2 DWORD ?
n3 DWORD ? 
prompt1 BYTE "Enter first number", 0 
prompt2 BYTE "Enter second number", 0 
prompt3 BYTE "Enter second number, z", 0 
string  BYTE    40 DUP(? ) 
resultLbl BYTE    "result", 0 
result     BYTE    11 DUP(? ), 0

.CODE    
_MainProc PROC 
input   prompt1, string, 40 
atod    string 
mov     n1, eax

input   prompt2, string, 40 
atod    string 
mov     n2, eax

input   prompt3, string, 40 
atod    string
mov     n3, eax

push n3 
push n2 
push n1

call Prog1 

add esp, 12
dtoa    result, eax 
output  resultLbl, result
mov     eax, 0 
ret    
_MainProc ENDP




Prog1 PROC 
push ebp 
mov ebp, esp 

push ebx

mov eax, [ebp + 8] 
imul eax, 3 
mov ebx, [ebp+12]
imul ebx, 7 
add eax, ebx 
mov ecx, [ebp+16]
imul ecx, 2 
add eax, ecx

pop ebx 
pop ebp
ret
Prog1 ENDP

END
```

Comment: And which part are you having trouble with?  You know how to input data, you are doing it 3 times already!

Comment: i want to loop the whole program again and again

Comment: It seems like what you need breaks into 3 steps: 1) Input a string.  2) Process the string to see what they entered.  3) Conditionally jump to an earlier point in the code.  Do you understand how to do step 1?

Comment: Yes. But i am having trouble with step 3 i guess.

Comment: Step 3 follows logically from step 2.  What have you written so far?  Are you familiar with conditional jump instructions?  `je` or `jne`?

Comment: related: [Why are loops always compiled like this?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926) shows several examples of how to make loops